# How to convert 34 facial landmark points to 68 points?

Tags: face-detection, dlib, google-cloud-vision

By using Google Cloud Vision it detects face and returns only 34 facial landmark points.
Is there any way to generate / derive 68 facial landmark points from the existing 34 landmark points like generating with [dlib](http://dlib.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own way of constructing 68 landmark points from 34 landmark points.

> - I selected 2 adjacent points and manually add a point between it through a loop.
> - I used Formula of drawing an arc to add a point, it is a bit more natural way instead of placing a point in the center of 2 points.